# What does these Verilog line of code mean?

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm looking at this code: https://github.com/hgeisse/eco32/blob/dfd24eb13387f16b7da99a2285df023f446a676a/fpga/experiments/de2-115/memctrl-32/sim/memctrl-1/ramctrl/ramctrl.v

and I've found two lines of code that I don't fully understand:

```
          if (| count[13:0]) begin
```

and

```
  assign data_addr_out_of_range = | data_addr[26:25];
```

I know that the symbol |, means **Bitwise OR** and **Reduction OR**.
But I continue without understanding the meaning in those lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to think of `|x` as `x != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

These are reduction-ORs as you suspect. It is a unary operator, whose result is the result of OR'ing all of the bits in the operand. For example, supposing that `x` is declared `reg[3:0]` with value `4'b0011`, `|x` is 1 while `|x[3:2]` is 0.

The first line indicates, "if any bit in `count[0:13]` is set, then perform the following block". The second indicates that `data_addr_out_of_range` is 1 if `data_addr[26]` is 1 or `data_addr[25]` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of poorly written code. The person who wrote it is thinking too much about the implementation, and not writing it at the RTLevel. Much better would be to write this as

```
if (count) begin
```

or

```
if (count !=0 ) begin
```

Anther problem is the variable `count` declared as

```
 reg [13:0] count;
```

and then referenced everywhere as `count[13:0]`. (Other variables are used the same way)

If you meant to use the entire variable, you should not add the extra part select. That way shows the intent better. The way this is originally written, if you ever change the width of `count` you have to go through the code and make sure you change it everywhere it's used.